# How to take out HDD (hard drive) from a G5

Tags: hard-drive, g5

G5 is totally defunct, I trying to take out the HDD for archive purpose.
But realize ... there is no way for me to take out the casing.
Any idea?

Comment: You should specify if this is referring to an iMac G5 or a PowerMac G5.  If it is an iMac then you should include whether or not it has an iSight camera, as the two different models are assembled quite differently.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I not sure G5 has two models. After googling, is confirmed a PowerMac G5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerMac G5's hard drives are fairly straight forward to remove.

1. Make sure to unplug the machine from power and disconnect all cables from the back of it.
2. Lift up the silver latch on the back side of the machine, this unlocks the door on the side of the machine.
3. Remove the door from the side of the machine
4. The hard drives are located in the upper right corner of the machine and are held in place by plastic tabs that rotate up and down
5. Flip/rotate the plastic tab holding the hard drive in place
6. Disconnect the two SATA cables from the hard drive.  This is kind of a tight fit but rocking the hard drive & cables will help to release them
7. Once the SATA cables are disconnected the hard drive should slide out.  The bottom one slides straight out, the upper one (if installed) drops a little bit then slides out.

[iFixit guide for removing PowerMac G5 hard drives](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Power+Mac+G5+Hard+Drive/1952/1) - Good reference with pictures

Comment: haha .. looks like not that hard, will try that once I have back to office.

Comment: with the photos, I manage to unplug hdd from 3 G5 in less than 10 minutes, thanks :)

Comment: Thats great to hear!  Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the G5 manual (late 2005): https://web.archive.org/web/20130514170019/http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/Power_Mac_G5_Late_2005.pdf

On page 45 it is explained how to open the casing and onward to how to change storage devices.

Hope that helps!